# How to block a user from Creating a PR (Pull Request) to Main brach from feature branch directly in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

How to block direct pull request creation from a 'feature' branch to the 'main' branch in Azure DevOps? (Block unnecessary PR creation). A developer can create a pr from a feature to a develop branch and from a develop to the main branch. But the creation of direct PR from feature to main branch needs to blocked/disabled.

Detailed description:

An user should be blocked/prevented from trying to create a pull request directly from a 'feature' to the 'main' branch. If possible that user should be warned the 'Direct PR creation is not allowed from a feature branch to main branch.
eg : A - feature branch, B - development branch, C - main branch
A to B is allowed, B to C is allowed, but A to C is not allowed.
We can block merge to a branch by adding policies at the branch level.
How can we block or unblock PR creation in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no such method can block users from creating a Pull Request when the source branch and target branch of the Pull Request are not in the correct order(For example:`feature -> master`)

Azure DevOps currently does not support custom pull request direction.

I can  understand your requirements. You could submit a suggestion ticket about this feature in [our UserVoice website](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion).

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I will verify this and will create a suggetion ticket for the custom pull request direction.

Comment: If you create a suggestion ticket,  you can share the link here. I will help you vote it.

Comment: Hi Kevin please check and vote this ticket https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Create-a-Pull-Request-order-for-branches/1537608